# How do I prevent find-file from filling in a file name?

Tags: spacemacs, find-file

Using spacemacs I usually open new files for editing with `C-s C-f` (for `find-file`), since that is recommended by [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47625/30425).

However I have an issue when the file I wish to open is both new (doesn't yet exist), and is a substring of an existing file.  For example:  I want to open `project/src/Types/List.hs` for editing, but there already exists `project/src/Types/InfiniteList.hs`.  So when I type the name of the file I wish to edit it selects the existing file from the list.

I tried also using neo-tree to create the file but it seems like it uses `find-file` to implement its file creation so the problem continues.

My current solution is to go to my terminal and `touch` the desired file before opening, but this is pretty annoying to do.  Is there some way to do this from within spacemacs?  Is there some alternative to `find-file` that I should be using here?

Comment: That isn’t the default Emacs behavior, so either you or Spacemacs have enabled something like `ido-mode` or similar.

Comment: @db48x It's definitely not `ido-mode`.  Turning ido mode on switches to `ido-find-file` which works quite differently (but still does the annoying behavior). I'm working with a fresh spacemacs installation out of the box, so it is possible it is cause by something else but I don't know what.  It certainly is default *spacemacs* behavior.

Comment: `ido-mode` is just one that I could remember off the top of my head; there are a number of other popular packages that improve Emacs along these lines. You’ll have to dive into the Spacemacs documentation and find out what it is doing.

Comment: I believe this is ivy, also called swiper behavior. If so, you might try the keys C-M-j (ivy-immediate-done)

Comment: @LynHeadley `C-M-j` drops me into the dired by name mode in the current directory.  I'm not sure what it is supposed to do, but that's what happens when I try it.

Comment: Please incorporate any relevant info from comments into the question itself (including updating tags, if appropriate). Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew What information are you thinking of specifically?

Comment: Not thinking of anything specifically. Got the impression that comments were perhaps beginning to specify the question further.

Comment: @LynHeadley I had this annoyance too and never bothered to look into it until now. I'm using normal Emacs though with `counsel-find-file` to find files. The `C-M-j` works for me on your exact example.

I have a directory with `InfiniteList.hs` I launch `counsel-find-file` (with `SPC f f` for me), type `List.hs`. It autocomplete to `InfiniteList.hs`, but pressing `C-M-j` ignores the completion and creates `List.hs`.

You should check what function your key binding is bound to. It might not be an ivy function, but a helm one instead (or something else).

Comment: @willbush Ah I see.  This actually solves my problem. `C-M-j` does indeed work.  Since I didn't know what it was supposed to do I didn't realize that I had to type the entire file name before `C-M-j`.  It makes perfect sense it dropped me into dired mode.